# How to check email and mobile and aadhar number present or not in my mongodb database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

require('../db/conn');
const User = require('../model/userSchema');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello World from the server from router.`);
});

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    
    const { name,email,phone,work,password,cpassword } = req.body;
    
    if(!name || !email || !phone || !work || !password || !cpassword){
        return res.status(422).json({error:"please fill all the fields data.."});
    }
    User.findOne({ "$or": [ { email: email }, { phone: phone} ] })
    .then((userExist) => {
        if(userExist){
            return res.status(422).json({error:"Email ID or Mobile No is already exist."});
        }

            const user = new User({name,email,phone,work,password,cpassword});
            
            user.save().then(() => {
                res.status(201).json({message:"User Registered Successfully."});
            }).catch((err) => res.status(500).json({error:"Failed to regsiter user."}));
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err)});
});
module.exports = router;

await User.findOne({ "$or": [ { email: email }, { phone: phone} ] });
```

This code worked for me. But if we want to differentiate both phone and email and aadhar number; so if `email id` is present than it will show it is present, and if `phone no` is present than it will show it is present, and if `aadhar no` is present than it will show.  To do this how can we write the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check userExist, which is the returned record from DB.

```
if(userExist.phone==phone)
 err="Phone No exist"
else if (userExist.aadhar==aadhar)
 err="Aadhar Exist"
```

Finally return the error string

Comment: I tried this but when i put the data unique then data is not push in database.   TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')
    at E:\MERN Project\Server\router\auth.js:20:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: sorry for coming back so late. Is the DB indexed for email and aadhar and mobile number  with unique constraint ? are you trying to insert duplicate ? did you check the payload before saving into DB ?